# Filter array item having max in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, max

My taxDetails object is carrying tax details.

Let's assume, it holds following data as for now.

```
taxDetails
[0] =>  name: praveen
        amount: 100
[1]=>   name: john
        amount: 125
[2]=>   name: eric
        amount: 80
```

Now I need to get the record having maximum amount

```
   var highestTax as  name: john
                      amount: 125
```

I tried following two methods, but not getting

```
var latestTax = value.taxDetails.filter(function (el) {
                        return Math.max.apply(null, el.amount);


var latestTax = value.taxDetails.filter(function (el) {
                        return max(el.tax_year);
```

How can I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var latestTax = taxDetails.sort(function(a,b){ return (a.amount - b.amount); }).pop();
```

Comment: Sort function needs to return 0, when values are equal and negative value if a < b. What you did is bogus / non-deterministic. Which means that it may or may not work, depending on the actual data present in the array.